# A validation attribute of type PropertyComparisonValidatorAttribute cannot be used to validate values

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-annotations

I am using `PropertyComparisonValidatorAttribute` as such:

```
    [PropertyComparisonValidator("Last", ComparisonOperator.LessThan)]
    public int First
    {
        [...]
    }

    [PropertyComparisonValidator("First", ComparisonOperator.GreaterThan)]
    public int Last
    {
       [...]
    }
```

However, when it is time for it to be validated, I get the following exception:

`A validation attribute of type PropertyComparisonValidatorAttribute cannot be used to validate values`

I don't know of any other way to validate one property based on the value of the other. To be clear, In my XAML form, I want to validate that the user inputs a first value Less than a second value or a second value Greater than a first value.

Comment: Isn't that attribute from the EntLib validation block framework? Have you tried using `[Compare("Last")]` instead (from the DataAnnotations namespace)?

Comment: Yes you are right. I tried the Compare attribute but that only indicates whether the two properties are equal, I want to ensure that one is smaller than the other @AndrewStephens

Comment: I found a few articles/questions mentioning the same error (but different validation attr). It sounds like the DataAnnotations framework throws this exception when it doesn't support that particular validator (but the articles don't explain *why* it doesn't like them). The only thing I can suggest is to write your own custom validation attribute, e.g.:- http://www.itorian.com/2013/07/custom-data-annotations-or-custom.html

Comment: Thanks @AndrewStephens, that's what I ended up doing. Post that as an answer to my question and I'll mark it as the answer (I find it's dirty to mark your own solution as the answer), it could help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced with similar problem while using custom validation attributes with my ASP.NET WebAPI.
It could be fixed by **defining Ruleset directly** in your validation attribute.

```
public class MyClass
{    
    [PropertyComparisonValidator("Last", ComparisonOperator.LessThan, Ruleset="Default")]
    public int First
    {
        [...]
    }

    [PropertyComparisonValidator("First", ComparisonOperator.GreaterThan, Ruleset="Default")]
    public int Last
    {
       [...]
    }
}
```

Then when you need to validate your object pass ruleset as parameter to **Validate** method:

```
MyClass target = new MyClass();
// Fill your target with data.
ValidationResults result =  Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validation.Validate<MyClass>(target, "Default")
```